# Fit a line to a heat map

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting

I have the following sample matrix:

```
m <- matrix(c(5,5,5,6,7,7,10,10,10,200,5,5,8,9,10,10,10,200,200,200,5,5,9,10,200,200,200,200,200,200,4,6,8,10,200,200,200,200,200,200,5,6,10,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,3,4,10,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,2,5,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,4,8,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,5,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

colnames(m) <- as.numeric(1:10)
rownames(m) <- as.numeric(10:1)
```

Matrix:

```
> m
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
10   5   5   5   4   5   3   2   4   5 200
9    5   5   5   6   6   4   5   8 200 200
8    5   8   9   8  10  10 200 200 200 200
7    6   9  10  10 200 200 200 200 200 200
6    7  10 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200
5    7  10 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200
4   10  10 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200
3   10 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200
2   10 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200
1  200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200
```

A heatmap of this data looks as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

longData <- melt(m)

ggplot(longData, aes(x = Var1, y=Var2)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value))
```

[image]

I would like to fit a curve to this heatmap.

**Expected output**
[image]

I have no idea how to address this problem. Is it possible to do this in R, and if so, how? In the end, I would like to be able to make a plot with just the curve (without the heatmap).

Comment: If you just want the curve, I would sum over the columns of `1-m`, giving you the array `[0,1,1,2,2,2,4,6,8,9]` and then fit a curve to that array. I have no experience with R tho, so I don't know exactly how to do that.

Comment: In case of a binary input, that would indeed be a smart option. But my data is non-binary, so I improved the sample code. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: What if you convert them to binary before summing? E.g. `(data>100).sum(axis=0)`

Comment: What do you mean by " fit a curve to this heatmap"? Why is that your expected output?

Comment: @agila please see my answer to this question.

Comment: @JamesPhillips thanks but, in my opinion, the original question is still unclear. It's not difficult to fit some curve to those data but I still don't understand how he wants to choose the curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something to get you started:

#### Data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

line <- longData %>%
    filter(value != 200) %>%
    arrange(Var1, Var2) %>%
    group_by(Var1) %>%
    summarize(Var2 = max(Var2)) %>%
    bind_rows(tibble(Var1 = 0,
                     Var2 = 0))
```

#### Code

```
ggplot() +
    geom_raster(data = longData,
                aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
    geom_smooth(data = line,
                aes(x = Var1, y = Var2), 
                method = "loess", se = FALSE)
```

#### Result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I extracted data from the heatmap as shown below, an made an equation search for equations with three or less parameters. A good candidate equation appears to be Scaled Power With Offset, "Var2 = a * pow(Var1, b) + Offset" woth parameters a = 3.2094504107129447E-02, b = 2.4442669641519590E+00, and Offset = 1.0648694513887436E+00 yielding RMSE = 0.383 and R-squared = 0.982.

[image: points]

[image: plot]